# Xcode change dynamic framework Product Module Name

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, lldb, module-map

I’m trying to change the product module name of a dynamic framework.
The main reason I’m doing this is that my framework is customised for each client, so I have different targets with different names and output files that I want to keep different as they are, but I would like the framework to be imported for all the targets with the product name.
The framework is in objective C and consumed by a swift application.

In the Xcode build settings the DefinesModule is set to YES.

Let’s say the product name is CustomerSDK and I want it to be imported as ProductSDK.
For example: The framework file will be `CustomerSDK.framework` and the import statement `import ProductSDK`.

If I use the `$(PRODUCT_NAME:c99extidentifier)` as the module name (the default option in Xcode) by calling `import CustomerSDK` it works, but  when I try to change the *Product Module Name* field in build settings to another one the code completion of Xcode in the host application project doesn’t find the module name and even if I write it I get the **“No such module ProductSDK”** error. Looking inside the resulting product framework I can see that no modulemap file is generated.

I tried also to create a custom module.modulemap file, in this case the code completion of Xcode in the host application project proposes the new name, but when I try to compile I still get the **“No such module ProductSDK”** error.

```
framework module ProductSDK {
  umbrella header "CustomerSDK.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }
}
```

Comment: Ever able to fix this? Running into the same issue myself.

Comment: No, it seems that is not possible. also reached Apple tech support and they gave me a workaround that was a viable solution for me. Basically exist a hidden setting in Xcode that make you change the path o the product, here the response `To apply this override, add this setting as a User Defined build setting in Xcode — CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR isn’t visible by default.` , but I still had time to try it

Comment: Thank you for answering! So what value did you have to give to `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR`? ProductSDK.framework?